# ICEfaces : No Factories configured for this Application exception

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-1.2, icefaces, icefaces-1.8

I am trying to run a simple 'Hello World' application using JSF1.2 and ICEfaces 1.8.
I have downloaded all the jars using ICEFaces plugin for Galileo, MyFaces library:

- backport-util-concurrent.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
- commons-codec-1.3.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.jar
- commons-digester-1.8.jar
- commons-discovery-0.4.jar
- commons-fileupload.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- FastInfoset.jar
- icefaces.jar
- icefaces-comps.jar
- jstl.jar
- jxl.jar
- krysalis-jCharts-1.0.0-alpha-1.jar
- myfaces-api-1.2.9.jar
- myfaces-impl-1.2.9.jar
- standard.jar
- ui.jar

Added them to the lib folder, and build path.

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>HelloWorld(ICE)</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.jspx</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>To allow multiple windows for a single application.</description>
    <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.concurrentDOMViews</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>Turn on/off application-wide synchronous or asynchronous updates.</description>
    <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.synchronousUpdate</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>Google Maps API key is required if gMap component is used. Sign up for an API key from http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html</description>
    <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.gmapKey</param-name>
    <param-value>ABQIAAAADlu0ZiSTam64EKaCQr9eTRTOTuQNzJNXRlYRLknj4cQ89tFfpxTEqxQnVWL4k55OPICgF5_SOZE06A</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.uploadDirectory</param-name>
    <param-value>upload</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
    <param-value>4048576</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.PersistentFacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.iface</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/block/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.component.inputfile.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/uploadHtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.icesoft.faces.util.event.servlet.ContextEventRepeater</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

My faces-config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd" version="1.2">
  <application>
    <view-handler>com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
  </application>
</faces-config>
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
  <%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" %>
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
      <html>

      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
      </head>

      <body>
        <jsp:forward page="ICEfacesPage.iface" />
      </body>

      </html>
```

ICEfacesPage.jspx:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<jsp:root version="1.2" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">

  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

  <f:view>
    <ice:outputDeclaration doctypeRoot="HTML" doctypePublic="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" doctypeSystem="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" />
    <html>

    <head>
      <title>ICEfaces, Ajax for Java EE</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
      <ice:outputText value="Welcome to ICEfaces." />
      <ice:form>
        <ice:panelGroup draggable="true" style="width:200px;border:1px solidblack;">
          <ice:outputText value="Hello World!" />
        </ice:panelGroup>
      </ice:form>
    </body>

    </html>
  </f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

Exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet Persistent Faces Servlet threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all
configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions! If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might
be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml. A typical config looks like this;
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:106) at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.
<clinit>(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:38) at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainSessionBoundServlet.
  <init>(MainSessionBoundServlet.java:136) at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet$3.newServer(MainServlet.java:87) at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.checkSession(SessionDispatcher.java:86) at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:45)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23) at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302) at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:709)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:680) at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:64) at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don't understand why the faces-initialization is not working. Please help me figure out how to fix the issue.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem.

I just had to add the following mapping to web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Source:
https://books.google.co.in/books?id=2rX6SMAIr-QC&pg=PT78&dq=No+Factories+configured+for+this+Application.&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Io_8VMvVM4arOq2WgdAK&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false